# await is a reserved word

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs

I have follow code that should fetch data asynchrony:

```
  methods : {
    btn() {
      console.log("Hello");
      var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
      let mydata = await fetch(url);
      console.log(mydata);
    }
  }
```

And I am getting error:
`Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/app3/src/App.vue: await is a reserved word (19:19)`

Comment: ...because it's not an `async` function

Comment: Reference the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator.

Comment: You can only use await inside a function marked as `async`. And functions marked as `async` always returns a promise

Comment: `fetch` is not async? Is it's possible to fix?

Comment: `btn` needs to be `async`, it is not related to `fetch`. You can only use `await` inside an `async` function. e.g. `async btn() {`